# UIPickerView Selectrow inComponent Not responding

Tags: ios4, uipickerview

I've a view part of tab bar controller. I've added a UIpickerview to the View. The delegate and data source of the uipickerview is the viewcontroller.

I've a coded like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]]; 
     self.arrCurrencies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.arrCurrencies addObject:@"USD"];
    [self.arrCurrencies addObject:@"GBP"];
    [self.arrCurrencies addObject:@"INR"];
    [self.arrCurrencies addObject:@"EUR"];
    [self.arrCurrencies addObject:@"YEN"];
    [self.arrCurrencies addObject:@"AUD"];
    [self.arrCurrencies addObject:@"SGD"];
    [self.pickerView reloadAllComponents];
    [self.pickerView selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:NO];

 }
```

I tried the above code,  it's not selecting the 3rd row or INR in the pickerview by default. Can someone suggest me where I'm wrong..!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see your .delegate method, but make sure you have it **in this order**:

```
mypicker.delegate = self;

[mypicker selectRow:[[General sharedInstance] displayMode] inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```

I had the delegate call method after the 'selectRow' method and I was mad looking for the solution in internet. 2 days with a lot of solutions, and only was this!!!

So, this doesn't work:

```
[mypicker selectRow:[[General sharedInstance] displayMode] inComponent:0 animated:YES];
mypicker.delegate = self;
```

A hint: My class is UIViewController child.